# Solving quadratic eigenvalue problem

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, eigenvalues

I am trying to solve a quadratic eigenvalue problem using Mathematica similar to Matlab command "polyeig"
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyeig.html

How to do it using Mathematica?

Comment: Is the repository function [MatrixPencilSolve](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/MatrixPencilSolve) relevant ?

Comment: Not  sure the way it works, I am trying to solve the example in the Matlab link using MatrixPencilSolve. But its not giving me any answer.